# Combine results of two unrelated queries into single view

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

Is it possible to combine the results of two separate (unrelated) sql queries into a single view. I am trying to total some figures for users and count the views for videos this month to display on a dashboard.

i.e.,

`select count(*) from video where monthname(views) = 'May';`

and

`select sum(sessions) from user where user_id = 6;`

I would like to create a view that combines that contains these two results.

Is this possible?

Comment: Like: `SELECT videoCount, SessionCount FROM (select count(*) AS VideoCount from video where monthname(views) = 'May') AS VideoStats CROSS JOIN (select sum(sessions) AS SessionCount from user where user_id = 6) AS UserStats` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.total_session,
       t1.watch_count
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS common_key,
          count(*) AS watch_count
   FROM video
   WHERE monthname(views) = 'May') AS t1
JOIN
  (SELECT 1 AS common_key,
               sum(sessions) AS total_session
   FROM USER
   WHERE user_id = 6) AS t2 ON t1.common_key = t2.common_key;
```

Ofcourse, this will be very efficient only when the output in both t1 and t2 is one row.

Comment: Why would the output be more than one row? They both aggregate everything into a single result, since there's no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Why do you need the `common_key` field? If you leave out the `ON` clause, you get a full cross-product. You can also use `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: I was just explaining in generic case :)

Comment: Yes you can, just wrote what I felt was better.

Answer (score 12):

If you want the results next to each other in separate columns you can simply `SELECT` a list of queries:

```
SELECT ( select count(*) from video where monthname(views) = 'May') AS May_CT
      ,( select sum(sessions) from user where user_id = 6) AS User_Sum
```

If you want the results stacked in one column:

```
select count(*) from video where monthname(views) = 'May'
UNION  ALL
select sum(sessions) from user where user_id = 6
```

The latter may require datatype conversion

Comment: This does answer the question as presented with their specific queries, but I'll point out the first query in this answer only works for subqueries that produce a single column. Which is not answering the question "Combine results of two unrelated queries into single view" in a universal way.