# How do I combine two nested MySQL queries into one View?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, subquery

I have two queries, almost similar, but never the less,They must be treated as separate as they have different meanings and values, I want to combine them into one view, I tied doing `UNION`, but the result was they were all combined into one table, which is not what I want, I would like them to appear as **entirely separate tables under one view**, here is what I did:

```
CREATE VIEW TEAM_SUMMARY AS
 SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY.country_name AS CountryName_T1,count(Team1)AS NoOfGames,
    SUM(Team1_score) AS TotalGoalsFor,SUM(Team2_score) AS TotalGoalsAgainst
    FROM COUNTRY,MATCH_RESULTS WHERE
    country_name = Team1
    group by country_name


    UNION 

 SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY.country_name AS CountryNameT_2,count(Team2)AS NoOfGames,
    SUM(Team2_score) AS TotalGoalsFor,SUM(Team1_score) AS TotalGoalsAgainst
    FROM COUNTRY,MATCH_RESULTS WHERE
    country_name = Team2
    group by country_name;
```

**UPDATE:
So, the output of my current query is something like this:**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM TEAM_SUMMARY;
+----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+
| CountryName          | NoOfGames | TotalGoalsFor | TotalGoalsAgainst |
+----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+
| Algeria              |         1 |             1 |                 1 |
| Argentina            |         4 |             5 |                 1 |
| Australia            |         2 |             2 |                 6 |
| Belgium              |         3 |             5 |                 2 |
| Bosnia & Herzegovina |         1 |             3 |                 1 |
| Brazil               |         6 |             7 |                13 |
| Cameroon             |         2 |             1 |                 8 |
| Chile                |         1 |             3 |                 1 |
| Columbia             |         3 |             7 |                 1 |
| Costa Rica           |         2 |             1 |                 1 |
| Croatia              |         1 |             1 |                 3 |
| Ecuador              |         1 |             0 |                 0 |
| England              |         1 |             1 |                 2 |
| France               |         3 |             5 |                 1 |
| Germany              |         4 |             9 |                 3 |
| Ghana                |         1 |             1 |                 2 |
| Greece               |         1 |             2 |                 1 |
| Honduras             |         2 |             1 |                 5 |
| Iran                 |         1 |             0 |                 0 |
| Italy                |         2 |             0 |                 2 |
| Ivory Coast          |         1 |             2 |                 1 |
| Japan                |         2 |             1 |                 4 |
| Mexico               |         1 |             1 |                 0 |
| Netherlands          |         4 |             4 |                 1 |
| Nigeria              |         2 |             3 |                 3 |
| Portugal             |         1 |             2 |                 1 |
| Russia               |         1 |             1 |                 1 |
| South Korea          |         2 |             2 |                 5 |
| Spain                |         2 |             1 |                 7 |
| Switzerland          |         2 |             4 |                 6 |
| Uruguay              |         2 |             3 |                 4 |
| USA                  |         2 |             2 |                 3 |
| Algeria              |         3 |             6 |                 6 |
| Argentina            |         3 |             3 |                 3 |
| Australia            |         1 |             1 |                 3 |
| Belgium              |         2 |             1 |                 1 |
| Bosnia & Herzegovina |         2 |             1 |                 3 |
| Brazil               |         1 |             4 |                 1 |
| Cameroon             |         1 |             0 |                 1 |
| Chile                |         3 |             3 |                 3 |
| Columbia             |         2 |             5 |                 3 |
| Costa Rica           |         3 |             4 |                 1 |
| Croatia              |         2 |             5 |                 3 |
| Ecuador              |         2 |             3 |                 3 |
| England              |         2 |             1 |                 2 |
| France               |         2 |             5 |                 2 |
| Germany              |         3 |             9 |                 1 |
| Ghana                |         2 |             3 |                 4 |
| Greece               |         3 |             1 |                 4 |
| Honduras             |         1 |             0 |                 3 |
| Iran                 |         2 |             1 |                 4 |
| Italy                |         1 |             2 |                 1 |
| Ivory Coast          |         2 |             2 |                 4 |
| Japan                |         1 |             1 |                 2 |
| Mexico               |         3 |             4 |                 3 |
| Netherlands          |         3 |            11 |                 3 |
| Nigeria              |         2 |             0 |                 2 |
| Portugal             |         2 |             2 |                 6 |
| Russia               |         2 |             1 |                 2 |
| South Korea          |         1 |             1 |                 1 |
| Spain                |         1 |             3 |                 0 |
| Switzerland          |         2 |             3 |                 1 |
| Uruguay              |         2 |             1 |                 2 |
| USA                  |         2 |             3 |                 3 |
+----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+
64 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**UPDATE2: Each query provides 32 row, and here they are combined into 64 rows so I don't know which belongs to which query, you can see that `USA` is the last row of each query and then it starts with `Algeria` again for the second query with different values that do not represent the column description.**

**What I want is something like this:**

```
+------+--------+    +------+--------+
| code | SUM(*) |    | code | SUM(*) |
+------+--------+    +------+--------+
| AAA  |      4 |    | AAA  |      4 |
| BBB  |      3 |    | CCC  |      1 |
+------+--------+    +------+--------+
```

Then I did some searching in order to use `JOIN` as shown here [Combine results of two unrelated queries into single view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700893/combine-results-of-two-unrelated-queries-into-single-view) but, this scenario is much less complicated than mine and couldn't apply it on my scenario, Any Idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "entirely separate tables under one view"? Can you provide some sample data and illustrate how the resulting view should appear?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @ Mureinik , @ Gordon Linoff .... done

Comment: UPDATE2 posted too.

Comment: If needed, consider this syntax with parentheses:  `( SELECT ... ) UNION ( SELECT ... ) GROUP BY .. ORDER BY ..` -- In this case the grouping and ordering is done after the `UNION`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One view doesn't product *two* result sets.  But you can identify where they come from:

```
CREATE VIEW TEAM_SUMMARY AS
   SELECT 'Team1' as which,
          c.country_name AS CountryName_T1, count(Team1) AS NoOfGames,
          SUM(Team1_score) AS TotalGoalsFor,
          SUM(Team2_score) AS TotalGoalsAgainst
    FROM COUNTRY c JOIN
         MATCH_RESULTS mr
         ON c.country_name = mr.Team1
    GROUP BY country_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Team2' as which,
           c.country_name AS CountryNameT_2,
           count(Team2) AS NoOfGames,
           SUM(Team2_score) AS TotalGoalsFor,
           SUM(Team1_score) AS TotalGoalsAgainst
    FROM COUNTRY c JOIN
         MATCH_RESULTS mr
         ON c.country_name = mr.Team2
    GROUP BY country_name;
```

Notes:

- `SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY` is almost always unnecessary (as in this case.
- Use `UNION ALL` by default.  Only use `UNION` when you specifically want to incur the overhead for removing duplicates.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The above adds a column `which` to specify where each row comes from.