# How to combine two independent mysql count query result in a single view

Tags: mysql

I have two independent queries as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER;
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM POSTS;
```

for these result I have created a mysql script file named as **total.sql**:

```
USE matchstix;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM POSTS;
```

when I ran this script at mysql shell then getting results as

```
mysql>source /home/total.sql;

    Database changed
    +-------+
    |COUNT(*) |
    +-------+
    | 94122 |
    +-------+
    1 row in set (0.03 sec)

    +----------+
    | COUNT(*) |
    +----------+
    |    94007 |
    +----------+
```

the question is here how can i get the result something like:

```
+----------+------------+
| COUNT(*) | COUNT(*)   |
+----------+-------------
|    94007 |  94122     |
+----------+--------------
1 row in set (0.44 sec)
```

is it possible if yes then how ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `SELECT` with sub-queries to show the totals in one row:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER) AS count_user,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM POSTS) AS count_post
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=76ee68d93fc7c3bd612aa70af356141f)

Comment: I would do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `JOIN` statement of SQL query. Basicly, you should write two select statement for two different table, and join them together into one view.

I would suggest you to take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23700994/1867076

Comment: thanks for you answer. but one thing i need to know how it is good rather then using sub-queries

Comment: Join on what exactly? you don't need a join here